# Application performance with media

Tags: android, performance, media-player, gallery, universal-image-loader

I have a gallery application which loads all the media (images, music and video) thumbnails.
I'm using Universal Image loader to load the images with following configs

```
DisplayImageOptions mOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
        .showStubImage(R.drawable.media)
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.media)
        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.media).cacheInMemory().cacheOnDisc()
        .build();
```

and

```
config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(mContext).enableLogging()
        .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir))
        .threadPoolSize(10).build();
```

This app works flawlessly on a 2GB ram device. But what i have observed is than on lower ram devices, the application is really laggy. Could someone tell me if these configuration are fine? or do i need to alter something to gain better performance in low end devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. 
`cacheInMemory(`) was the problem. This will have performance problems in low end devices. or 1GB ram devices.
Also i suggest you not to use unlimited cache. i.e `UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir))`.
Use limited cache since it will take up lot of memory. In my case it was almost 1.2GB on my phone.
Having altered these options. I'm having a good performance.